# Possible to disable ESLint/Prettier rule that adds parentheses?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

If I write:

```
const a = 1;
const b = 1;
const c = 1;
const d = 1;

const t = a * b * (c + d) / 100;
```

then some rule wants to change to:

```
const t = (a * b * (c + d)) / 100;
//        ^               ^ unwanted parentheses
```

I don't want the extra parentheses, but I can't figure out if it is ESLint or Prettier that adds them. My `.eslintrc` added below:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": ["./tsconfig.json"]
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "no-console": 1,
    "prettier/prettier": 2,
    "no-case-declarations": 0,
    "no-extra-parens": 2,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-extra-parens": 2
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  }
}
```

Update

Here is what happens when I hover without the parentheses.

[image]

Comment: is the reason you don't want them because of the two extra bytes in the file? there's no actual difference in the results with / without those parentheses

Comment: It's clearly **not** ESlint, because you have both `no-extra-parens` and `@typescript-eslint/no-extra-parens` set to error (sidenote: I'd recommend using `"error"` rather than `2`), which if you run the linter will report the extra parentheses.

Comment: When you say _"some rule"_, what have you done to find out which (mouse over the error, run the linting from the command line, look at the problems list, ...)?

Comment: Eslint doesn't reformat your code. Prettier does. Or possibly some other plugin.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have now added a screenshot of then I hover the error. When I do `npx prettier -c test.ts` then I just get `Code style issues found in the above file. Forgot to run Prettier?`. If I `npx -c -w test.ts` then it adds the parentheses.

Comment: If you're asking how to configure Prettier (note it has relatively few options) see https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html, or for the ESLint plugin https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier#options.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I still haven't gotten closer to how to disable this behaviour...

Comment: @SandraSchlichting according to the [Prettier docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#javascript) you can also disable it for a single line

Answer (score 1):

It is Prettier that adds them and it can't be disabled. See https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/12554

> Prettier used to print as few parentheses as possible, then it
> switched to print some extra ones for readability. See the very long
> #187 for the full story.

In the thread `dprint` is suggested as an alternative to Prettier.  Downgrading Prettier to the 2017 version could also be an option. Or perhaps there is an active fork of Prettier that doesn't add the parentheses.